# Sumar y acumular con respecto a una columna en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

actualmente tengo dos tablas, una de semana:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla_semana` (
 `id_semana` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `name_semana` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tabla_semana` (`id_semana`, `name_semana`) VALUES
('1', 'sem 1'),
('2', 'sem 2'),
('3', 'sem 3'),
('4', 'sem 4');
COMMIT;
```

y la tabla trabajos:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `trabajos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `tipo_trabajo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `region` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `fecha_generado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `semana_generado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `estado_generado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `fecha` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `semana` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `estado` varchar(20) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


  INSERT INTO `trabajos` (`id`, `tipo_trabajo`, `descripcion`, `region`, `fecha_generado`, `semana_generado`, `estado_generado`, `fecha`, `semana`, `estado`) VALUES
  (1, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '1/01/2019', '1', 'crq solicitado', '1/01/2019', '1', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (2, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '1/01/2019', '1', 'crq solicitado', '1/01/2019', '1', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (3, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '1/01/2019', '1', 'crq solicitado', '1/01/2019', '1', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (4, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '3/01/2019', '1', '', '3/01/2019', '1', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (5, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '3/01/2019', '1', 'crq solicitado', '3/01/2019', '1', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (6, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '4/01/2019', '1', 'crq solicitado', '4/01/2019', '1', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (7, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '5/01/2019', '1', 'crq solicitado', '5/01/2019', '1', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (8, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '7/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '7/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (9, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '8/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '8/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (10, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '8/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '8/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (11, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '8/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '8/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
    (12, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '8/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '8/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (13, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '8/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '8/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (14, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '9/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '9/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (15, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '9/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '9/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (16, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '9/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '9/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
    (17, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '10/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '10/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
    (18, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '11/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (19, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '11/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (20, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '11/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (21, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '11/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (22, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '11/01/2019', '2', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (23, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '11/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (24, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '12/01/2019', '2', '', '12/01/2019', '2', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (25, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '10/01/2019', '2', '', '15/01/2019', '3', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (26, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '10/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '15/01/2019', '3', 'PENDIENTE'),
   (27, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '10/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '15/01/2019', '3', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (28, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '16/01/2019', '3', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (29, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '11/01/2019', '2', 'crq solicitado', '16/01/2019', '3', 'EJECUTADO'),
   (30, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '10/01/2019', '2', '', '17/01/2019', '3', 'PENDIENTE');

  ALTER TABLE `trabajos`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

  ALTER TABLE `trabajos`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
  COMMIT;
```

entonces lo que estoy tratando es de que se sumen en dos filas, uno con respecto a la columna de "semana_generado" y el otro con respecto a columna "semana". el codigo es el siguiente:

```
  SELECT  pc.region,
    pc.id_semana semana,
    pc.tipo_trabajo,
    IFNULL(count(IF(t.estado_generado="crq solicitado",1,null)),0) trab_generados,
    IFNULL(count(IF(t.estado="EJECUTADO",1,null)),0) trab_ejecutados
  FROM (SELECT *
        FROM (select region from trabajos group by region) t1
        CROSS JOIN (select id_semana from tabla_semana group by id_semana) t2
        CROSS JOIN (select tipo_trabajo from trabajos group by tipo_trabajo) t3
    ) pc
  LEFT JOIN trabajos t
    ON pc.region = t.region
    AND pc.id_semana = t.semana
    AND pc.tipo_trabajo = t.tipo_trabajo
  GROUP BY pc.region,
         pc.tipo_trabajo,
         pc.id_semana
```

pero todo me suma y acumula con respecto a la columna "semana" pero yo quiero que "trab_generados" me sume y acumule con respecto a "semana_generados". Debe ser porque el join esta uniendo el "id_semana" con la columna "semana", pero no encuentro la manera de como realizarlo

intente cambiando el "trab_generados" poniendo lo siguiente

```
   IFNULL(count(IF(t.estado_generado="crq solicitado" and 
  pc.id_semana=t.semana_generado,1,null)),0)
```

pero no me cuenta algunos campos

lo que busco es que se una lo resaltado de estas dos imagenes

cuando haga el join con columna "semana"(pc.id_semana = t.semana)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando haga el join con columna "semana_generado"(pc.id_semana = t.semana_generado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

habra alguna manera de que se pueda realizar esto?

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos la sailda actual y cual te gustaria que fuera la salida? en un query no vas a poder acumular de dos formas distintas.. por lo menos en un solo query

Comment: Adhiero a lo que dice gbianchi, no se entiende bien cual es la dificultad ¿Llevar un acumulado de cada fila? ¿Abrir las sumas por semana en columnas distintas? Si pudieras mostrar la salida esperada, creo que quedaría mucho más clara la pregunta.

Comment: acabo de añadir dos imagenes, creo que el detalle es en el join

Comment: ¿Es decir, en la fila 2, que aparece un 5 y un 2 quisieras que diga 7?

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses los alias, eso sirve en algunos casos